# contractVerifierMessaging.receive is null

Tags: automated-tests, spring-kafka, testcontainers, spring-cloud-contract

I'm setting up contract tests for Kafka messaging with Test Containers in a way described in [spring-cloud-contract-samples/producer_kafka_middleware/](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/producer_kafka_middleware). Works good with Embedded Kafka but not with TestContainers.

When I try to run the generated ContractVerifierTest:

```
public void validate_shouldProduceKafkaMessage() throws Exception {
    // when:
    triggerMessageSent();

    // then:
    ContractVerifierMessage response = contractVerifierMessaging.receive("kafka-messages",
    contract(this, "shouldProduceKafkaMessage.yml"));
```

**Cannot invoke "org.springframework.messaging.Message.getPayload()" because "receive" is null**
is thrown

Kafka container is running, the topic is created. When debugging receive method I see the message is null in the message(destination);

Contract itself:

```
    label("triggerMessage")
    input {
        triggeredBy("triggerMessageSent()")
    }

    outputMessage {
        sentTo "kafka-messages"
        body(file("kafkaMessage.json"))
```

Base test configuration:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE, classes =  {TestConfig.class, ServiceApplication.class})
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class BaseClass {
```

What am I missing? Maybe a point of communication between the container and ContractVerifierMessage methods?

Comment: Can you please share the code that you use for settings up the `Testcontainers` based `KafkaContainer`?

Comment: `static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(
            DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.3"));

            @DynamicPropertySource
    static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) throws IOException {
 
        kafkaContainer.start();
        registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
        registry.add("spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
        registry.add("spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
       }`

Comment: please double check how we do things with Spring Cloud Contract and testcontainers here https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/main/producer_kafka_middleware

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by adding a specific topic name to listen() method in KafkaMessageVerifier implementation class.

So instead of @KafkaListener(id = "listener", topicPattern = ".*"), it works with:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"my-messages-topic"})
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord payload, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it solved by changing from `ConsumerRecord<String, Map<?, ?>> payload` to simply `ConsumerRecord payload`